# PHP + Fcgid hangs if download interrupted

Tags: php, apache-2.2

**Note:** admins, please vote for migration to ServerFault.

I'm using a LAMP setup with PHP running through `mod_fcgid`.  For most requests this works well, but I've noticed that when I download a file but interrupt the download before it's complete, the php-cgi process that was serving the file blocks attempting to write more data until it the `IPCCommTimeout` is reached.  Once the timeout is reached, the process gets interrupted and the process starts servicing other requests again.

Is there some available setting for fcgid that I can set to have it abort if nothing is capturing the output?  Is there something I can do in PHP to handle it?

The problem doesn't occur if the download isn't interrupted; in fact, I only noticed it because I was trying to stream a FLV file using gddflvplayer, which seems to send a brief request to get the first few frames, then another to play it, and this causes the same problem.

FYI, this is the strace of the hanging cgi process; it sits like this until it's eventually interrupted, presumably by the process manager when the `IPCCommTimeout` is reached.  My guess is that it's hanging trying to output the results of the `readfile()` call, but Apache is no longer listening (as the request has been cancelled by the user).

```
root@some-machine:~# strace -p 24837
Process 24837 attached - interrupt to quit
write(3, "\5|A\313%\35\337\376\275\237\230\266\242\371\37YjzD<\322\215\357\336:M\362P\335\242\214\341"..., 17432
```

The logs indicate that the request is eventually reaped due to the timeout

```
mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 240 seconds
```

The download code more or less just uses `readfile` to serve up the file, with a few headers involved as well (note: in this code, `Header` is more or less just a wrapper around `header()` to avoid problems in tests).

```
$filepath    = '/some/path/foo.flv';
$filename    = 'foo.flv';
$disposition = 'inline';

$h = Header::get();
$h->send('Pragma: public');
$h->send('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
$h->send('Content-type: ' . FileSystem::get()->getMimeType($filepath));
$h->send('Content-Length: ' . FileSystem::get()->getFileSize($filepath));
$h->send('Content-Disposition: ' . $disposition . '; filename="' . $filename . '"');
$h->send('Content-transfer-encoding: 8bit');
$h->send('Expires: 0');
$h->send('Pragma: cache');
$h->send('Cache-Control: private');

flush();
readfile($filepath);
```